# Want to pass the java value into javascript function in jsp

Tags: java, jsp, struts

I am trying to pass a string value to a JavaScript function by taking from request parameter in JSP, in my struts based project. here is the code:

```
<%
String timeVal = "Not found";   
    if(request.getAttribute("myDate")!=null){       
        timeVal= (String)request.getAttribute("myDate");
    } 
%>
```

and then pass it in function as parameter

```
<html:submit property = "save" styleClass = "button_c" onclick = "return SubmitPage('update', <%=timeVal %>)">Save</html:submit>
```

Where the JavaScript function is

```
function SubmitPage(action, aa)
{   

alert("Date is  ...." + aa);

}
```

But when i try to run this it gives me an error

```
HTTP Status 400 - Request[/AMResourceLibraryListAction] does not contain handler parameter named ref
```

With message on web page.

```
Request[/AMResourceLibraryListAction] does not contain handler parameter named ref
```

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT** Here is stack trace

```
[ERROR] DispatchAction - -Request[/AMResourceLibraryListAction] does not contain handler parameter named ref
```

Comment: Post your full stacktrace here please. A stacktrace contains the **cause** of the exception thrown.

Comment: @BuhakeSindi added but it does not show much details on stack trace :(

Comment: have you seen whats the value coming there by seeing viewsource?

Comment: When do you get the error? Are you able to press the submit button?

Comment: @mudalov When i pass the <%= timeVal %> as parameter in save function it gives me error. this is the only condition

Comment: Then please try to use quotes, as suggested by Sekhar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it's work for me :

```
<html:submit property = "save" styleClass = "button_c" onclick = "return SubmitPage('<%=timeVal %>')">Save</html:submit>
```

('<%=timeVal %>') // between single Quotation

Comment: This way avoid the exception but take <%=timeVal %> as string not variable

Comment: in this question `timeVal` is a **String**, If it is not, can Convert?

Comment: timeVal is a variable of type String having variable value... that i am getting from a servlet....

Answer (score 3):

Rather using that i will advise you to use value like this in your JavaScript function

```
var tt = <%=(String)request.getAttribute("myDate")%>
alert(tt+ "Done this....");
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Use '`<%=timeVal %>`' instead of `<%=timeVal %>` in Javascript method:

```
<html:submit property = "save" styleClass = "button_c" onclick = "return SubmitPage('update', '<%=timeVal %>')">Save</html:submit>
```

Comment: This way avoid the exception but take <%=timeVal %> as string not variable