# Pass parameter to JavaScript through Java code

Tags: java

I'm trying to define a generic Formula, e.g. "a+b" and use it to pass parameters. Any ideas how to make this thing work?

```
    ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
    ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
    String Formula="a+b";

    engine.put("Formula", Formula);
    engine.put("a", "3");
    engine.put("b", "4");
    res = engine.eval("r = Formula").toString();
    System.out.println(res);
```

The output of the above code is "a+b" and not 7 as expected.

Comment: Look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15682881/want-to-pass-the-java-value-into-javascript-function-in-jsp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To bind variable names with values, use Bindings.

I thing the following code solves your question:

```
ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
String formula="a+b";

Bindings bindings = engine.createBindings();
bindings.put("a", 3);
bindings.put("b", 4);

engine.setBindings(bindings, ScriptContext.ENGINE_SCOPE);

Object res = engine.eval(formula);
System.out.println(res.toString());
```